# WiX tool - installer does not add file to installation directory

Tags: c#, wix

I am using WiX tool 3.10 to create an installer of a simple C# application. I have followed the tutorial in the official documentation, but I have the following issue: I need to add a .txt file in the application directory, but the installer only adds the executable of the application. Here is the XML of the .wxs file:

the directory structure:

```
<Fragment>
<!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Controllore">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>    
</Fragment>
```

adding files:

```
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
      <Component Id="Controllore.exe" Guid="ce2f6f3f-73b4-4fa9-9c3f-76685d520fdb">
        <File Id="Controllore.exe" Source="MyPath\Controllore.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="param.txt" Guid="5ffe84e4-5893-48be-af86-1731bcd176ca">
        <File Id="param.txt" Source="MyPath\param.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Step 3: Tell WiX to install the files -->
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="Controllore.exe" />
      <ComponentRef Id="param.txt" />
    </Feature>
  </Fragment>
```

and at the end, I have to add these lines, otherwise the installer won't install anything:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
  <Component Id="CMP_Controllore">
    <File Source="$(var.Controllore.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: WIX?   Run away.  Run far, far away.

Comment: I like WIX, you just need to get into the right mind set for it.

Comment: At least it's not installshield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to rearrange the way you have it set up. I've found trying to work with fragments to be really frustrating while learning to first use WiX. I don't know that it's the preferred way of doing it since maintainability on larger products would be a lot more of a hassle, but I have something like this (given your file names):

```
<?xml ...?>
<Wix ...>
  <Product ...>
    <Package ... />
    <MajorUpgrade .../>
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Controllore">
          <Component Id="Controllore.exe" Guid="ce2f6f3f-73b4-4fa9-9c3f-76685d520fdb">
            <File Id="Controllore.exe" Source="$(var.Controllore.TargetPath)" 
                    KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="param.txt" Guid="5ffe84e4-5893-48be-af86-1731bcd176ca">
            <File Id="param.txt" Source="$(var.Controllore.TargetDir)param.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="Controllore.exe" />
      <ComponentRef Id="param.txt" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

For smaller projects, I find it much easier to just put all the relevant information directly into the Directory and not worry about fragments. Obviously, if you have to work on a team with a large project, that's not reasonable.

Comment: I have tried your code but it is not working: where the package tag is closed it seems that only </Product> is expected. If I remove the </Package> more errors occur: "Unresolved reference to symbold Media:1 in section Product.*". That's one for each file tag.

Comment: @SamuRed Fixed that, sorry. I have the media template in there just to embed the cabinet file that WiX creates. Does it still throw an error if you add `EmbedCab="yes"` to to the MediaTemplate?

Comment: the XML code is now ok. An error occurs on the file tag of the file param.txt: it seem that it can't find the file, but oddly the error reports the correct path of the file and I am sure the file exists!

Comment: ok solved it! Don't know why but deleting and creating a brand new file solved the problem. Thanks for your help @Melovitz

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that a fragment isn't processed unless it's referenced by another fragment.  Then the entire fragment is processed atomically.

I have an Open source project called ISWIX (http://iswix.codeplex.com).  It contains VS project templates and graphical designers to really help you get up to speed faster.  Then you can look at how it organizes it's fragments and see how it all comes together and decide for yourself how to proceed.

Here is a short 2 minute video where I 1) create a desktop application and 2) create a WiX/IsWiX installer for it.  It's really that easy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnV_OU6fk8c

Comment: Thanks, I will surely try your tool but right now I am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: Send me an invite on DropBox (chrpai@iswix.com) with your EXE  and I'll have an installer project for you in 10 minutes.